# How to make pull down Page refresh on Web app using jQuery Mobile or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a simple web application, I want to give the ability to the user to refresh the page with pull down refresh thing like android or iOs.

the refresh it will only lead to reload the page nothing else :

```
location.reload();
```

I'd like to use jQuery Mobile or Javascript.

Comment: Have you read anything about this? Have you tried other code?

Answer (score 6):

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/fzhdz1jv/4/)

This is on `body` but you can have it in other elements of course. In this example `html` and `body` are with `100% height` and different `background-color`s so you'll notice when dragging the body down. Mouse moves down more than `200px` and page will reload.

```
var mouseY = 0;
var startMouseY = 0;
$('body').on('mousedown', function (ev) {
    mouseY = ev.pageY;
    startMouseY = mouseY;
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (e.pageY > mouseY) {
            var d = e.pageY - startMouseY;
            console.log("d: " + d);
            if (d >= 200)
                location.reload();
            $('body').css('margin-top', d/4 + 'px');
        }
        else
            $(document).unbind("mousemove");


    });
});
$('body').on('mouseup', function () {
    $('body').css('margin-top', '0px');
    $(document).unbind("mousemove");
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('body').css('margin-top', '0px');
    $(document).unbind("mousemove");
});
```

Comment: That's amazing !!! Thanks, But is there any way to pus instead an animated spinner ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great plugin for pull to refresh

https://github.com/luis-kaufmann-silva/jquery-p2r

add the js to your head

script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".scroll").pullToRefresh({
             refresh:200
        })
        .on("refresh.pulltorefresh", function (){
            location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="scroll">
    <div class="refresh">
        Pull To Refresh 
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        content
    </div>        
</div>
```

do a minus margin-top on the scroll class to make the pull to refresh to be hidden, change refresh:200 to how long the pull takes to refresh. e.g at the moment its set to refresh after its pulled for 200 pixels

Answer (score -2):

First, your application is in position to detect the scrolling event.
Do like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
   if($(this).scrcollTop()>='somevalue may be your window height')
          location.reload();
});
```

I think this is gonna work for you.

Comment: Really? This is not gonna work.